# C++ variadic template specialization in function parameter getting error

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, specialization

I have a variadic template specialization as the following:

```
template <typename T> struct MakeASXFunc;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct MakeASXFunc<R (Args...)>
{
    std::tuple<Args...> m_args;
    void operator ()(Args&&... args)
    {
        m_args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
};
```

And when I need to use this:

```
MakeASXFunc<void (int, int)> f;
f(54, 54);
```

I will get an error:
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Why is it like this? the operator overload function takes variadic arguments, how this error is even possible?

P.S. I'm using MSVC++ 15.6.2

Comment: Please extract an MCVE. Also, one suggestion, only use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for macros.

Comment: @JiveDadson I'm using this to extract arguments for another time

Answer (score 1):

This line, you are calling a tuple:

```
    m_args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

Obviously a tuple is not callable. Use assignment:

```
    m_args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Comment: Yeah, my bad :) I was trying to initialize the tuple on constructor and... that happened. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.